# cross browser compatiblity with loader

Tags: javascript, asp.net, jquery, cross-browser

I have problem with Loader with other browsers except IE. The code goes as follows.
Below is my Div tag code in Master Page.

```
<div id="pnlPopup" class="PrProgress" style="display: none;">
        <div id="innerPopup" class="PrContainer">
            <div class="PrHeader">
                Loading, please wait...</div>
            <div class="PrBody">
                <img src="Images/activity.gif" alt=" "/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Javascript function in Masterpage as below

```
$(document).ready(function () {

            Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(endRequestHandler);        
            Sys.Application.add_load(applicationLoadHandler);
            Sys.Application.add_unload(applicationUnloadHandler);
            Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(endRequestHandler);
            Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_beginRequest(beginRequestHandler);
        });
```

My CSS as follows

```
<style>
  .PrProgress
{
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    padding: 2px 3px;
}
.PrContainer
{
    border: solid 1px #808080;
    border-width: 1px 0px;
}
.PrHeader
{
    background: url('Images/sprite.png') repeat-x 0px 0px;
    border-color: #808080 #808080 #ccc;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 0px 1px 1px;
    padding: 0px 10px;
    color: #000000;
    font-size: 9pt;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 1.9;  
    white-space:nowrap;
    font-family: arial,helvetica,clean,sans-serif;
}
.PrBody
{   width: 220px;
    height: 19px;
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
    border-color: #808080;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 0px 1px;
    padding: 10px;
}
    </style>
```

Following are scripts added in Hedaer Tag

```
<script src="js/jquery-1.8.3.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/pgbScript.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Following is pgbScript.js code

```
function applicationLoadHandler() {
    /// <summary>Raised after all scripts have been loaded and the objects in the application have been created and initialized.</summary>
};
function applicationUnloadHandler() {
    mainForm.CleanUp();
    mainForm = null;
    Sys.Application.dispose();
};
function beginRequestHandler() {
    /// <summary>Raised after an asynchronous postback is finished and control has been returned to the browser.</summary>
    mainForm.StartUpdating();
};
function endRequestHandler() {
    /// <summary>Raised before processing of an asynchronous postback starts and the postback request is sent to the server.</summary>
    // Set status bar text if any was passed through the hidden field on the form
    mainForm.EndUpdating()
};
var mainForm = 
{
    pnlPopup : "pnlPopup",
    innerPopup : "innerPopup",
    updating : false
};
mainForm.StartUpdating = function() {
    mainForm.updating = true;
    mainForm.AttachPopup();
    mainForm.onUpdating();
};
mainForm.EndUpdating = function() {
    mainForm.updating = false;
    mainForm.DetachPopup();
    mainForm.onUpdated();
};
mainForm.onUpdating = function(){
    if(mainForm.updating) {
        var pnlPopup = $get(this.pnlPopup);
        pnlPopup.style.display = '';         
        var docBounds = mainForm.GetClientBounds();
        var pnlPopupBounds = Sys.UI.DomElement.getBounds(pnlPopup);
//        var x = docBounds.x + Math.round(docBounds.width / 2) - Math.round(pnlPopupBounds.width / 2);
//        var y = docBounds.y + Math.round(docBounds.height / 2) - Math.round(pnlPopupBounds.height / 2);       
        var x = docBounds.x + Math.round(docBounds.width / 2) - pnlPopupBounds.width;
        var y = docBounds.y + Math.round(docBounds.height / 2) - pnlPopupBounds.height;
        Sys.UI.DomElement.setLocation(pnlPopup, x, y);
        //if(Sys.Browser.agent == Sys.Browser.InternetExplorer) {
            if(!pnlPopup.iFrame) {
                var iFrame = document.createElement("IFRAME");
                iFrame.scrolling= "no";
                iFrame.src = "nothing.txt";
                iFrame.frameBorder = 0;
                iFrame.style.display = "none";
                iFrame.style.position = "absolute";
                iFrame.style.filter = "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(style=0,opacity=0)";
                iFrame.style.zIndex = 1;
                pnlPopup.parentNode.insertBefore(iFrame, pnlPopup);
                pnlPopup.iFrame = iFrame;
            } 
            pnlPopup.iFrame.style.width = docBounds.width + "px";
            pnlPopup.iFrame.style.height = docBounds.height + "px";
            pnlPopup.iFrame.style.left = docBounds.x + "px";
            pnlPopup.iFrame.style.top = docBounds.y + "px";
            pnlPopup.iFrame.style.display = "block";      
        //}  
    }           
}
mainForm.onUpdated = function() {
    // get the update progress div
    var pnlPopup = $get(this.pnlPopup);
    // make it invisible
    pnlPopup.style.display = 'none';
    if(pnlPopup.iFrame) {
        pnlPopup.iFrame.style.display = "none";
    }
}; 
mainForm.AttachPopup = function() {
    /// <summary>
    /// Attach the event handlers for the popup
    /// </summary>
    this._scrollHandler = Function.createDelegate(this, this.onUpdating);
    this._resizeHandler = Function.createDelegate(this, this.onUpdating);    
    $addHandler(window, 'resize', this._resizeHandler);
    $addHandler(window, 'scroll', this._scrollHandler);
    this._windowHandlersAttached = true;
};
mainForm.DetachPopup = function() {
    /// <summary>
    /// Detach the event handlers for the popup
    /// </summary>
    if (this._windowHandlersAttached) {
        if (this._scrollHandler) {
            $removeHandler(window, 'scroll', this._scrollHandler);
        }
        if (this._resizeHandler) {
            $removeHandler(window, 'resize', this._resizeHandler);
        }
        this._scrollHandler = null;
        this._resizeHandler = null;
        this._windowHandlersAttached = false;
    }
};
mainForm.CleanUp = function() {
    /// <summary>
    /// CleanUp all resources held by mainForm object
    /// </summary>
    this.DetachPopup();
    var pnlPopup = $get(this.pnlPopup);
    if(pnlPopup && pnlPopup.iFrame) {
       pnlPopup.parentNode.removeChild(pnlPopup.iFrame);
       pnlPopup.iFrame = null;
    }
    this._scrollHandler = null;
    this._resizeHandler = null;
    this.pnlPopup = null;
    this.innerPopup = null;
    this.updating = null;
};
mainForm.GetClientBounds = function() {
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the width and height of the browser client window (excluding scrollbars)
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns type="Sys.UI.Bounds">
    /// Browser's client width and height
    /// </returns>
    var clientWidth;
    var clientHeight;
    switch(Sys.Browser.agent) {
        case Sys.Browser.InternetExplorer:
            clientWidth = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
            clientHeight = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
            break;
        case Sys.Browser.Safari:
            clientWidth = window.innerWidth;
            clientHeight = window.innerHeight;
            break;
        case Sys.Browser.Opera:
            clientWidth = Math.min(window.innerWidth, document.body.clientWidth);
            clientHeight = Math.min(window.innerHeight, document.body.clientHeight);
            break;
        default:  // Sys.Browser.Firefox, etc.
            clientWidth = Math.min(window.innerWidth, document.documentElement.clientWidth);
            clientHeight = Math.min(window.innerHeight, document.documentElement.clientHeight);
            break;
    }
    var scrollLeft = (document.documentElement.scrollLeft ? document.documentElement.scrollLeft : document.body.scrollLeft);
    var scrollTop = (document.documentElement.scrollTop ? document.documentElement.scrollTop : document.body.scrollTop);
    return new Sys.UI.Bounds(scrollLeft, scrollTop, clientWidth, clientHeight);
}; 
if(typeof(Sys) !== "undefined")Sys.Application.notifyScriptLoaded();
```

The loader works fine in IE. But whenever I am browsing in other browsers getting error as
*The Resource Cannot be found.* in Local system.
When i hosted the same code in Production server.
1) First it will display Loader
2) Next 404, error Page cannot be found
3) After few seconds i will get page requested.

Please let me know how to avoid *The Resource Cannot be found.* and *404, Page cannot be found* error in middle of the request.

**Below is the error from production server**

Server Error

404 - File or directory not found.
The resource you are looking for might have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.

**and below is the error from Local system from my Application**

Server Error in '/ExecutionSystem' Application.

The resource cannot be found.

Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.

Requested URL: /ExecutionSystem/nothing.txt

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.1

Comment: What does the net tab say in chrome's console?

Comment: Thanks, Question is edited for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Try giving a more specific src i.e. :

```
iFrame.src = "~/nothing.txt";
```

because Internet Explorer sometimes resolve some small errors in code that other browsers don't.